# Change Pandas default NA type promotions

Tags: python, pandas, casting

I have this particular case where I have huge integers in input
and the conversion in **float64** actually change the value.

> According to this page :
>   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions
>   Pandas converts automatically integers with NA to float64.

The problem is when I have NA value in my inputs, pandas automatically cast it to `'float64'` even if I specify `'Int64'` in the constructor

I wrote a repl.it script with pandas 1.0.1 and python 3.8.1 showing my use case :
https://repl.it/@RonanTREILLET/pandastestint

For those who don't want to play it, here is basically what I do :

```
test_df =[
    {'dataset_id': 327626200612520493}, 
    {'dataset_id': 327626200612520493}, 
]
df = DataFrame(data=test_df, columns=['dataset_id'])
```

then if I do

```
print(df[col_name])
```

the output is :

```
0    327626200612520493
1    327626200612520493
Name: dataset_id, dtype: int64
```

which is **correct**

**but, if I do this** :

```
print(df[col_name].astype('float').astype('Int64'))
```

I have this output :

```
0    327626200612520512
1    327626200612520512
Name: dataset_id, dtype: Int64
```

which is **wrong**.

The main problem is when you create dataframe with NA inputs like this :

```
#test with a NA value in DF, showing how Pandas automatically cast to `'float64'`
test_with_nan_df =[
    {'dataset_id': 327626200612520493}, 
    {'dataset_id': None}
]
df_w_nan = DataFrame(data=test_with_nan_df, columns=['dataset_id'])
print(df_w_nan[col_name].astype('Int64'))
```

or

```
df_w_nan_int64 = DataFrame(data=test_with_nan_df, columns=['dataset_id'], dtype='Int64')
print(df_w_nan_int64[col_name])
```

the output is the same :

```
0    327626200612520512
1                  <NA>
Name: dataset_id, dtype: Int64
```

As you may see, even if I force `'Int64'` during the dataframe creation it's still the wrong value and I suppose pandas internally cast column to `'float'` before casting it to `'Int64'`

So **IF** my usage of Pandas is correct, I'd like to write a patch to **override the NA type promotion's method**.

Did someone already did this ? and is it even possible ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `object` to ensure that pandas leaves the data unchanged. Then you can manually set the types.

```
pd.DataFrame(data=test_with_nan_df, columns=['dataset_id'], dtype='object').astype('Int64')
#           dataset_id
#0  327626200612520493
#1                 NaN

#dataset_id    Int64
```

Comment: and if I want don't know the type of every column in my inputs, object type is quite more memory consuming than Int64 isn't it ? Changing the NA type promotion would help create the right type and consume less memory I guess

Comment: @RonanT yes I definitely agree. I'm hoping someone comes up with a slightly better answer. numeric-like IDs and zip codes (things with leading 0s to preserve) are always problematic. You can specify only those columns as `str` and then convert just them instead of messing up the entire DataFrame. most `pd.read...` will allow you to specify different dtypes for each column.

Comment: @RonanT On the other hand, I'm not sure whether `Int64` will necessarily have a smaller memory footprint than `object`. Especially if you're never going to do math with them, it might not be totally necessary to convert. I'm not sure about the performance of other operations, like merges or mappings.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure either :p but let's say for exemple I know that a specific input may contains huge int and NA in one unkown column. I'd like to change default type promotions for this particular case instead of forcing every column to object then try to guess every type for each column because, except in this case, pandas do it very well for me !